# PyCharm and Django's request object auto-completion

Tags: django, autocomplete, namespaces, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm with Django and it has a problem with Django's `request` object. When I write a view like :

```
# File: views.py

def page(request):

    foo = request.G[TAB]   # When I click TAB here, it can't auto-complete
                           # GET unless I used it somewhere else.

    return render_to_response("page.html")
```

It looks that PyCharm can't see the object `request`. How do I fix this issue or work around it?

Comment: I'm curious, what do you expect it to show when you hit `tab`?

Comment: It should list the possible methods that their names begin with G or just complete it if there is only one method begins with G, `request.GET` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not a good idea use get parameters in Django like you try
And I think PyCharm devs try to teach us write DRY code

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

```
#urls.py

...
url(r'^page/(?P<page_number>[0-9]*)$', 'app_name.views.pages'),
...
```

and

```
#app_name: views.py
...
from django.shortcuts import render
def test_page(request, page_number=1):
    return render(request, 'test_tpl.html',{'page_number': page_number})
...
```

Comment: Thanks "b1-" for the answer, but it's really has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Sp. pycharm dev think that this is "feature" 
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5401

Comment: I first thought it's a bug. Thank you for the link, you saved me a lot of trouble.